# Wordpress: Calling a php function out of javascript: ReferenceError: <function> is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using Gravity Forms "after submission" event to call a javascript function out of the `functions.php` file.

There are 3 files involved:  `frontend-checklist.php`, `frontend-checklist.js` and `functions.php`.

The GF Form is displayed in a lightbox and once the form is complete and the submit button is pressed, the GF even function pulls a specific field out of the GF form and passes it to the javascript function.

I am then configuring an Ajax call to insert/update a different database table with that information.

Everything seems to work, right up until the Ajax call, it never seems to call the php function to write the data to the database.

Here is the code out of my `functions.php`:

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_5', 'GF_Submit_5', 10, 2);

function GF_Submit_5($entry, $form){

?>
 <script>
    var vcl_c = <?php echo json_encode($entry['19']); ?>;
        frontend_checklist_fc_database_write(vcl_c );
 </script>  
<?php
}
```

The above code calls a javascript function.  Here is that function:

```
function frontend_checklist_fc_database_write(fc_itemID) {

alert ("javascript - dbwrite" + fc_itemID);
    var data = { action: 'fc_database_write', fc_itemID: fc_itemID };
    jQuery.post(frontendChecklist.ajaxurl, data);

}
```

Finally, here is the code that defines the Ajax call to actually write the data, as well as the configuration of the action and the enqueue.  This code is in a third file (outside of the javascript code and the `functions.php` files).

```
add_action('wp_ajax_fc_database_write', array('Frontend_Checklist', 'dbWriteAjax'));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array('Frontend_Checklist', 'add_js'));

function add_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('frontend-checklist', plugins_url('frontend-checklist.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));

    wp_localize_script( 'frontend-checklist', 'frontendChecklist', 
        array( 
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );
}


public static function dbWriteAjax() {
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_ID == 0) die;
        $ca = (int)$_POST['fc_itemID'];
        $fc_completed = "'on'";

        $casql = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT completed from wp_fc_vendorlist WHERE fc_vendorID = ' .$user_ID. ' and fc_itemID = ' .$ca. ' ORDER BY fc_itemID ASC' );
        $cachk = $wpdb->get_row($casql, ARRAY_A);
        $table_name = 'wp_fc_vendorlist';
    if($cachk =='') {
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name (fc_itemID, fc_vendorID, completed) VALUES ($ca, $user_ID, $fc_completed)"));
    } else {
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET completed = $fc_completed WHERE fc_vendorID =  $user_ID  and fc_itemID = $ca"));
    }       


    die;
}
```

The Alert in the javascript will fire, and I can track the javascript code with firebug and it seems to be updating the variables correctly. The error : ***ReferenceError: frontend_checklist_fc_database_write is not defined*** presents itself as soon as the code drops into the javascript function.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be using `plugins_url('frontend-checklist.js', __FILE__)` as the path to the script, but you only mention `functions.php`, which seems to suggest that you're writing a theme, not a plugin? Are you sure your `frontend-checklist.js` is being properly imported to the page? Check with your favourite browser's debugging tools. Certainly, if it wasn't, that would cause it not to be defined.

Comment: Sorry, that part may have been a bit unclear.

I am writing a plugin.  

The Gravity Forms "after submission" event code must be placed in the functions.php file (according to their support people).

I have edited the above question to relate the following:

There are 3 files involved: frontend-checklist.php, frontend-checklist.js and functions.php.

The Gravity Form is being displayed in a lightbox.

Comment: Okay, but you know that, unlike a theme, with a plugin the `functions.php` file isn't automatically included, right? I'm guessing they advise you to put it in `functions.php` because they assume you'll be writing a theme, where that file *would* be automatically included. And, like I said, check your browser's web inspection tools, and see whether the javascript is being included or not. It's the best way to figure out what's going on.

Comment: No, I did not know that the functions.php was not automatic.

The code out of the functions.php and the frontend-checklist-js are being loaded and run, can I assume that they are being properly loaded?  The page that is built by the frontend-checklist.php file is being properly built, the GF form is being loaded into a lightbox by a button press on that form.  I'm using the web inspection tools to get the error message that I quoted above.